# Python tkinter saving image name

Tags: python

I am beginner at python.
I want to save image file order by 1...10
But in my code,

```
save_path='/home/..'
for i in range(1,10)
    name=i
fullname=os.path.join(save_path,str(name))
img.save(fullname)
```

The image name is saved as '9.png'
How can i solve it?

Comment: See how to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python range function is upper bound exclusive, so you have to write this like:

```
  save_path='/home/..'
    for i in range(1,11)
        name=i
    fullname=os.path.join(save_path,str(name))
    img.save(fullname)
```

Which gives you 1 to 10 range.